# Rails 3 - If I'm using RSpec, can I just delete the 'test' folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

While trying to migrate, I keep getting this error:

```
rake aborted!
test-unit is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
```

If I'm using RSpec, can I just delete the test folder altogether?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072662/how-to-remove-unit-test-and-replace-it-with-rspec

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This error means that somewhere inside your project there is a `require test-unit` without it being specified in the `Gemfile`.

So you should actually try to find that statement and remove it to fix this error (or add the dependency to the gemfile --but that sounds a bit backwards if you are not using it).

Anyway: you can definitely remove the `test` folder if you are using `rspec`.

Comment: Usually, if you're using test unit, in your `/config/application.rb` there should be a `require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'` - which might be what's tripping you up.

Answer (score 1):

I believe so.  Rspec should only be looking for tests in ../spec/*

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can delete the test folder.

If you want test-unit though (due to other gem dependencies) here's how to install test-unit as a gem:

1. Add gem to Gemfile

   `gem 'test-unit'`
2. Check gems

   > bundle check

   Your Gemfile's dependencies could not be satisfied
     Install missing gems with `bundle install`
3. Install

   > bundle install

Should be good to go.