# can't activate test-unit (= 1.2.3), already activated test-unit-2.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake-task, ruby-on-rails-2

Recently I added rspec test in my rails 2.3.5 but I wasn't able to run simply `rake -T` command. Then I found [Rails 3 - If I'm using RSpec, can I just delete the 'test' folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915534/rails-3-if-im-using-rspec-can-i-just-delete-the-test-folder) and I added gem `test-unit` in my Gemfile. This is showing me below message.

```
rake aborted!
can't activate test-unit (= 1.2.3), already activated test-unit-2.3.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
```

Comment: So, to be clear, you're using bundler with Rails 2.3?

Comment: Yes, I am. I don't think there is something to do with bundler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to load old version of `test-unit` where new version is already activated. To fix this bug do either one

1.Removing your new version of `test-unit`

2.Find `test-unit` `1.2.3` version in rake file and replace it with `2.3.0`

Answer (score 2):

You must to doing something like `config.gem 'test-unit', :version => '1.2.3'` somewhere in test.rb. Remove this line and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
bundle exec rake -T
```

That will run the rake command in the context of your bundle which should lock in the correct version of all of your gems.